# VHDL and how they work

Tags: vhdl

I'm sorry if this has been asked before and I know its such a broad answer but i'm confused about some parts of VHDL. The part that is confusing me is does the VHDL go on the platform or is it merely a prototype of how the design will work?

Then we have FPGA which can be changed and to change you need VHDL (correct me if i'm wrong). So does that mean that the VHDL is stored somewhere on the device\SOC or am I completely wrong in my understanding.

For example we have the following package for AMBA [here](http://microelectronics.esa.int/soc/amba.vhd).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VHDL is a text description of the circuit or hardware configuration you require.  The VHDL description will be compiled to produce a binary file that can be used to configure the FPGA.  The VHDL text itself will not be loaded into the FPGA.